# Sphere spectrum, Thom spectrum, and Madsen-Tillmann bordism spectrum

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, stable-homotopy, spectral-sequences, cobordism

This is a following up question of [Sphere spectrum, Character dual and Anderson dual](https://mathoverflow.net/q/312618/27004).

What are the differences and the significances of the following:

(1). Homotopy classes of maps from a [**Thom spectrum**](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02566923.pdf) to a shift of the Anderson dual to the sphere spectrum?

(2). Homotopy classes of maps from a [**Madsen-Tillmann bordism spectrum**](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485892397) to a shift of the Anderson dual to the sphere spectrum?

It looks to me that [Madsen-Tillmann bordism spectrum](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485892397) is a close relative of
[Thom spectrum](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02566923.pdf). So what will be the comparison, differences, similarity between the two Homotopy classes above?

p.s. I suppose my Journal Article links above/below for two spectra are 100% correct. Please correct me if I am imprecise or I miss the Refs.

- R. Thom, Commentarii Mathematici Helvetici 28, 17 (1954).
- S. Galatius, I. Madsen, U. Tillmann, and M. Weiss, Acta
  Math. 202, 195 (2009)

Comment: If $X$ is any spectrum, $[X, \Sigma^n I\mathbb Z]$ fits into a short exact sequence  as described [in this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/312629/97265) -- in particular, it can be quickly determined from the homotopy groups of $X$. Therefore the question reduces to the difference between the homotopy groups of a Thom spectrum and the homotopy groups of a Madsen-Tillmann spectrum, and [this MathOverflow question and answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/179164/97265) is probably a good place to start for that.

Comment: A Madsen-Tillmann spectrum ``is'' a Thom spectrum! You may look at Section 2 of the following paper for a general construction:  

Søren Galatius and Oscar Randal-Williams. Stable moduli spaces of high-dimensional manifolds. Acta Math.,
212(2):257–377, 2014.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little confused by your question. You seem to be implying that the Madsen-Tillmann spectra are not Thom spectra, but this is not true: the definition of the spectrum $MTG(n)$ (for $G = O,SO,U$) is as the Thom spectrum of the virtual bundle $-\gamma_n$ over $BG(n)$, where $\gamma_n$ is the universal bundle. In general, computing $[X^\mu, I_\mathbf{Z}]$ for $X^\mu$ a Thom spectrum is equivalent to (the nontrivial task of) computing $\pi_\ast(X^\mu)$. Generally, one calculates this via the Adams spectral sequence (think back, e.g., to the original calculation of $\pi_\ast(MU)$). See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07530.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04264.pdf for nice expositions.